# Multiple choice question - Able to have the question correct with any correct answer

Tags: 7, quiz

I am using the *Quiz* and the *Multiple choice* modules. In a question, I have two answers correct and I'm hoping to have the question marked right, if any of the answer is chosen.

Right now, if both answers are chosen, only then the question is marked as correct by the module.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option " Score if chosen and Score if not chosen " in multichoice question.

Set `Score if not chosen = 1 and Score If chosen = 1`

I hope, It would fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in this way, if both of these are not choosen, it'll still correct it